# why does this function download an entire web page?

Tags: django

views.py

```
def download_file(request,path):
    file_path=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as enm:
            response=HttpResponse(enm.read(),content_type="application/adminupload")
            response['Content-Disposition']='Inline;filename='+os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
```

template index.html

```
<div>
    {% for post in file %}
    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    <a href="{{post.admin.upload.url}}" class="home__button anime-text" download="{{post.admin.upload.url}}">DOWNLOAD CV</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

urls.py

```
    re_path(r'^download/(?P<path>.*)$',serve,{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

I am trying to download a pdf file when i hit download, the function downloads the webpage and saves it with an extension of (.htm)

Comment: There is no call of `download_file` in shown code. Also unclear what value is `post.admin.upload.url`. and what does downloaded page contain? 404 page or something valid?

Comment: Are you sure you have the PDF link here `{{post.admin.upload.url}}`. Please provide the code clearly, we don't see any connection between View, template and url files.